# Maximum time allowed to complete authentication has been exceeded

Tags: openid, azure, dotnetopenauth

I am using [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/)  to authenticate an app on Windows Azure. From time to time, the system is slow, and I end up with the following error message

> Login failed: The maximum time allowed to complete authentication has been exceeded. Please try again.

Any suggestion how to increase this timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your .config file to change this line:

```
<openid maxAuthenticationTime="0:05">
```

(Taken from [this code snippet page](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net:8000/wiki/CodeSnippets/Configuration))

Answer (score 0):

Note for other folks: IF this keeps happening, it can also be to do with the ASP.NET cache flushing, on development machines this is quite possible.

Can verify this with

```
<caching>
  <cache disableMemoryCollection = "true"
    disableExpiration = "false"
    privateBytesLimit = "0"
    percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit = "90"
    privateBytesPollTime = "00:02:00"/>
</caching>
```

In System.Web in Web.Config